# ACCDE Label Wizard "Application-Defined or Object-Defined error"

Tags: vba, ms-access

Have been searching online for a solution to a problem that seems to be fairly unique. Using MSAccess 2016 we have a labels program that we package and distribute in ACCDE format. On the switchboard we have a button that launches the label wizard.

```
Application.Run "acwzmain.mlbl_Entry", "QryName"
```

Here is the problem. The labels wizard launches without fuss and the process to create labels can be followed to conclusion but upon clicking the finish button the wizard raises an error:

> Application-Defined or Object-Defined error

Has anyone encountered this problem? Does anyone have a solution?

Additional Info:

- This does not happen in ACCDB format (IE. it works perfectly)
- Trusted location for AccWiz files are correct
- In ACCDE mode we have dissalowed full menus and hidden the navigation pane.
- The same occurs in runtime mode (ACCDR)
- Database code has been compiled.
- Compact and repair has no affect.
- Since the error is confined to the Wizard itself and only occurs in ACCDE there is no way to debug and find offending code.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In an .accde and in Runtime mode, there is **no design view** for forms/reports. I have never used the Label wizard, but I guess this is the cause. => There is probably nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

SO after more research and Andre' advice it would seem that indeed it is due to the wizard's access to design view and the fact that a packaged MSAccess database doesn't allow design view which causes the conflict here. Our resolution was to use VBA to block users from being able to access VBA modules and so on so that the wizard is available. one could also just merge the data to Word and have the user set up the labels from the options in word.